# Does python have asynchronous web client requests (like C# async/await)? Or is each call fundamentally synchronous (like Java 1.8)?

Tags: java, python, c#

Im writing a Python client for a restful service so that I can make requests within a python application. There already exists a C# and a Java client and Im trying to figure out which of the two clients I should follow as a guide. So does python have asynchronous web client requests (like C# async/await)? Or is each call fundamentally synchronous (like Java 1.8)? I am not asking for a recommendation for a software library, programming language, etc. What I'm asking is if the python runtime has a web client class that can make async requests like C#. Or if it's like Java 1.8 where all it has is the synchronous calls.

Comment: How on earth is this closed for asking for a recommendation for software/libraries? He's asking if python as a web client class that can do async calls to a REST service.

Comment: have a look at asyncio (https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) combined with aiohttp (https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the Asyncio library

```
import asyncio

async def wait_around(n, name):
    for i in range(n):
        print(f"{name}: iteration {i}")
        await asyncio.sleep(1.0)

async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(*[
        wait_around(2, "coroutine 0"), wait_around(5, "coroutine 1")
    ])

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Comment: asyncio does not let you make async web requests. As Greg mentioned in his comment, you have to use aiohttp.

Answer (score 0):

> What I'm asking is if the python runtime has a web client class that can make async requests

No, the runtime itself does not have support for async web requests, and using asynchio as per the previous answer doesn't work for web requests.

I know you said you weren't looking for library recommendations, but for completeness sake, the only way I've seen to make async web requests from python is by using the
[aiohttp package](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/index.html).